# How to develop a parser for sql statements?

Tags: sql, parsing

Is there an example available which can help me to develop a parser to check whether a SQL statement is syntactically correct or not. 
Any source where I could learn to use parsing tools for the purpose?

Comment: The normal way of doing this is to use the database you are connected to, either in parse-only mode or to return a result set (which you ignore).

Answer (score 0):

Examples of SQL parsers are available in all the open source SQL databases.

[MySQL](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server)
[Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/)
[h2o](https://code.google.com/p/h2o-database/source/browse/)